# Authenticating with Rest Service in Java/Groovy

Tags: java, http, drupal, authentication, groovy

### Goal

I am a newbie on Groovy and Drupal 7. My project is to create a node on Drupal 7 via REstfull services using Groovy language. I have setup Rest Server on Drupal 7 and checked with mozilla plugin Poster with sending some authentication and creation Post requests. It works perfectly fine.

### Problem

However problem comes while establishing same process with Groovy/Java. I used `HttpBuilder` that basically works on top of Apache `HttpClient`.

In order to authenticate I need to send username/password to a `/user/login` URI. Next time I need to do something, such as a POST request ( e.g. create a Drupal node ), I need to use a different URI e.g. `/node` and **somehow** pass that auth data (`session_name` and a `session_id` that Drupal sends back the first time) with that POST request => that currently does not seem to work:

```
401 Unauthorized: Access denied for user 42 "trader785876"
```

### I Tried

- to copy cookies from the first (auth) request to the second
- to extract cookies from the first request, and set them in a header of the second
- to extract cookies from the first request, and set them in the POST parameters of the second, etc..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried authenticating using the method here http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/auth.html ?

```
...
authClient.auth.basic 'myUsername', 'myPassword'
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I figured out the solution. I used RestClient class instead of HttpBuilder it worked perfectly fine.